# Filemaker WebPublishing connections not timing out?

Tags: filemaker

I'm running FileMaker Server 13; It's running extremly slow because connections are not timing out [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j3AR.png)

I have [Guest] set up as read-only access (locally) using fmxml.. how do I force time out the connection?

Comment: I think the timeout for CWP is set by default to 3 minutes. Are you sure these are CWP users? Can you post a sample xml call?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new privilege and with fmxml, the create new user with that privilege. XML users don't use concurrent connection and there is no timeout.